# Where do I put the licensing code for my app? (Android)

Tags: android, android-lvl

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html

I don't know where to put this code for licensing.

Comment: Doesn't the linked web page tell you?

Answer (score 1):

RTFM! Did you read the whole text?

[image]

As you can see it should been started from your main activity. The logic itself should been in a seperat class so you can validate your licences also in other projects or activities.

Comment: Thanks for reading the manual for me. It doesn't load too well on my Windows 2000 system.

Comment: Your system seems to be a little outdated.

Comment: At least I'm using the fastest browser, Internet Explorer.

Comment: Uh Wikipedia says that the latest compatible Internet Explorer for Windows 2000 is version 6.0... No wonder that you have trouble viewing that page.